# ¿Como puedo establecer la salida de sonido a 5.1 canales en manjaro deepen?

Tags: linux, configuración, audio

Hace un tiempo soy usuario de manjaro deepen, y en estos momentos necesito configurar su salida de sonido a 5.1 canales de audio utilizando los tres conectores traseros del pc. Consulte algunas guías donde me indican modificar el archivo de configuración de Alsa, pero al hacerlo sigue como por defecto aun después de reiniciar el pc. Les dejo las imágenes de la configuración hecha para que me indiquen que puedo hacer. Gracias

Esta es la configuración que puse en el fichero daemon.conf

```
/etc/puse/daeon.conf


; daemonize = no

; fail = yes

; allow-module-loading = yes

; allow-exit = yes

; use-pid-file = yes

; system-instance = no

; local-server-type = user

; enable-shm = yes

; enable-memfd = yes

; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB

; lock-memory = no

; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes

; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes

; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20

; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes

; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto

; log-level = notice

; log-meta = no

; log-time = no

; log-backtrace = 0

resample-method = speex-float-6

; avoid-resampling = false
enable-remixing = yes

; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
lfe-crossover-freq = 120

flat-volumes = no

; flat-volumes = yes

; rlimit-fsize = -1

; rlimit-data = -1

; rlimit-stack = -1

; rlimit-core = -1

; rlimit-as = -1

; rlimit-rss = -1

; rlimit-nproc = -1

; rlimit-nofile = 256

; rlimit-memlock = -1

; rlimit-locks = -1

; rlimit-sigpending = -1

; rlimit-msgqueue = -1

; rlimit-nice = 31

; rlimit-rtprio = 9

; rlimit-rttime = 200000

default-sample-format = s24le

default-sample-rate = 44100

alternate-sample-rate = 48000

default-sample-channels = 6

default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe

; default-fragments = 4

; default-fragment-size-msec = 25

; enable-deferred-volume = yes

; deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 8000

; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

Comment: si pudieras poner texto en vez de imágenes sería mejor, recuerda que no todos los usuarios tienen la capacidad visual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la configuración del archivo está bien, el paso que fataba hacer es:
en un terminal ejecutar 
$ alsamixerluego precionar F6 y escojer la tarjeta de sonido. Haciendo esto aparece un master de sonido en el terminal, nos movemos con la flecha derecha hasta donde dice chanels (canales)y dándole a la flecha superior cambiamos los canales hasta que aparesca 6 y salimos. Ya esta.